# how to fix "MultiValueDictKeyError " in django 2.1.3'

Tags: django, python-3.x

i am trying to retrieve the 'name' value from :

```
  <input type="text" name="fullname" value="">
```

and display it on another page, but i keep getting MultiValueDictKeyError  when i call  `request.GET["fullname"]`, but if i use `request.POST.get('fullname', False)`  it returns None.

### views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')

def index(request):
    fn= request.GET["fullname"]
    crs= request.GET["course"]
    st='your welcome to first_app/index.html'
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html',{'st':st,'fn':fn,'crs':crs})

def courses(request):
    string= 'my name is ibi'

    return render(request,'first_app/courses.html',{'st':string})
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns =[

path('',views.index, name='index'),
path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses'),

]
```

### Traceback

[image: Traceback image]

please how can i correct this error and display the name value on another html page

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your form was not submitted correctly.

Form submitted using `<form method="get">` data will be available in `request.GET` and submitted content will be displayed on url.

To prevent key error you can set default value, default value will be set if there's no key exist in dictionary `request.GET('fullname', None)`and later you can validate it.

Similarly `<form method="post">` data will be available in `request.POST`.

You can access form's raw data in `request.body` regardless of method used.

Comment: I tried using `request.GET('fullname', None) ` and method in form is `<form method="get">` but im still getting thesame error

Answer (score -1):

Your input field is broken (missing `id` attributed):

```
 <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="foo">
```

Not sure how the rest of your form looks like, but assuming that it has the following attributes:

```
<form action='.' method='POST'>
</form>
```

what you'll want to do is modify your `index` view:

```
def index(request):
    context = {'st': ''your welcome to first_app/index.html'', 'fn': '', 'crs': ''} # you want a default context
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context['fn'] = request.POT.get('fullname')
        context['crs'] = request.POST.get('course')
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html',{'st':st,'fn':fn,'crs':crs})
```

You'll look for information submitted through the form only on `POST` requests.

Some good reading for you:

[Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

[How Django views work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/)

**Later edit:**
I'm pretty sure you're view is crashing when you try to load the page; That's because you have `request.GET['fullname']` but you don't have anything like that in your URL. That's why it's recommended to use `.get()`

```
ipdb> request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/lol/'>
ipdb> request.GET
<QueryDict: {}>
ipdb> request.GET['fullname']
*** django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'fullname'
ipdb>
```

Comment: id attribute is not used by django for form submission, its entirely for front-end purpose.